# REST Explorer for WCF

Tags: asp.net, wcf, rest

I am working on a WCF project; customer requested a sandbox page, a place to test and capture a request and show the response headers.

exactly like Microsoft rest explorer, myspace rest explorer, etc

http://rex.mslivelabs.com/

How can I create something like that?

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

use the great [WCF Web Api](http://wcf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20started%3a%20Building%20a%20simple%20web%20api) -  see section 7 - Test the Contacts API